# Modifying object in Collection in SelectedItem of TreeView

Tags: .net, wpf, binding, treeview, datacontext

Object Model:
Client has many studies has many subjects has many records. The treeview holds the clients/studies/subjects and the records are in the MainDataGrid.

Problem: When I modify one of the two-way binding properties on the Record object in the datagrid the setter on the Record object is never called. I am unsure how to approach the issue because I still don't understand enough about the wpf binding model/object model to figure out the reason for this.

This is NOT an MVVM app. In the codebehind, during the _loaded event, I load some data and assign it to the TreeView's datacontext via a well-implemented ObservableCollection.
On the TreeView's SelectedItemChanged event, I load related records and hookup property-changed handlers.

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HPA.Studies.MCA.Client"
Title="Medra Coding Assistant" Height="800" Width="1250" MouseRightButtonDown="HandleRightClick">
<Window.Resources>
    <local:HistoryTypeConverter x:Key="HistoryTypeConverter" />
    <DataTemplate x:Key="MedraValuesTemplate">
        <UniformGrid Columns="2" Rows="5">
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="MedDRA LLT:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CodeValue2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="MedDRA PT:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CodeValue1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="MedDRA HLT:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CodeValue3, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="MedDRA HLGT:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CodeValue4, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="MedDRA SOC:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding CodeValue5, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </UniformGrid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <TextBlock Text="Medra Coding Assistant" FontSize="15" FontWeight="Bold" />
        <TextBlock Text="Available Batches:" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Grid x:Name="BindingRootGrid"  Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="5*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView x:Name="tvClients" Grid.Column="0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource NavigatorTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        </TreeView>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="6" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="MainDataGrid" Grid.Column="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=tvClients, Path=SelectedItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Records}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridHyperlinkColumn Header="    " />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Discrim" Binding="{Binding Discriminator, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field Name" Binding="{Binding FieldName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Field Value" Binding="{Binding FieldValue, Mode=OneWay}" Width="160">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MedDRA Value" CellTemplate="{StaticResource MedraValuesTemplate}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <GridSplitter Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="6" Panel.ZIndex="1" />
        <DataGrid x:Name="HistoryDataGrid" Grid.Column="2" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  DataContext="{Binding ElementName=MainDataGrid, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=HistoryList}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="DateTime" Binding="{Binding Path=TimeStamp, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Event Type" Binding="{Binding Path=Description, Converter={StaticResource HistoryTypeConverter}, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Data" Binding="{Binding Path=Data, Mode=OneWay}" Width="80">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                        <Style>
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="User" Binding="{Binding Path=UserName, Mode=OneWay}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
    <Border Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
        <TextBlock Text="Control Panel Goes here" />
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

The Missing TreeView ItemTemplate:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="BatchesTemplate" ItemsSource="{Binding Formats}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=BatchName}" />
    <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12640543/996194). The problem was fixed by setting the UpdateSourceTrigger to LostFocus.

This is strange to me, because according to [MSDN on UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.100).aspx):

> Bindings that are TwoWay or OneWayToSource listen for changes in the target property and propagate them back to the source. This is known as updating the source. Usually, these updates happen whenever the target property changes. This is fine for check boxes and other simple controls, but it is usually not appropriate for text fields. Updating after every keystroke can diminish performance and it denies the user the usual opportunity to backspace and fix typing errors before committing to the new value. Therefore, the default UpdateSourceTrigger value of the Text property is LostFocus and not PropertyChanged.

So I'm not sure why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` if you want to change the Source as soon as you change the text in your TextBox. For `TextBox` defualt is `LostFocus`.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding YourBinding, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: You are correct according to the documentation, see my post and MSDN quote. I don't understand why the LostFocus wasn't working by default.